# How to send what'sapp message to any number from flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, sms, whatsapp

I am using an api to get users data and i want to send messages to every users what's app number on click in flutter app. How to do this ?

Comment: you cannot send a WhatsApp message from another app. the best you can do is open WhatsApp with contact and message composed. You have to manually press the send button once the app is opened with a deticated message. Maybe you can try with any python script or test script to press the button by the position but that is highly difficult and not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-wW2ZoDuFO4&t=391s

if windwos platform u can see my video

Comment: bro, i tried your code, it's not working @B14ck

Comment: it's for windows

Answer (score 0):

Use the plugin.

https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

```
final url = "https://wa.me/91XXXXXXXXXX?text=Hello";

//do not forgot to enter your country code instead of 91 and instead of XXXXXXXXXX enter phone number.

if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(url))) {
  await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url));
} else {
  showSnackBar(message: "Can't share link", title: "Error");
}
if (!await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url))) throw 'Could not launch $url';
```